# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datetime': Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, strftime

This is my code:

```
# Fetch today's date
Date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S')
# Variable for log file 
LogFile = os.getcwd()
print(LogFile)
os.mkdir("Logs12")
f = open("Password_Expiry_Date_Log_"+(Date)+".txt", "w+")

#Date Calculations
Date_Before = Date.datetime(Days_Before)
Days_After = Date.datetime(Days_After)
```

When I try to initialize the variable 'Date_Before', i get the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datetime'. However, I need date to be in a string format to write in into a text filename. Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Umm, you need to check the strptime docs. You are converting a date to  a string representation and then trying to get back the date from the <b>string</b>. Strings don't have a datetime attribute. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: You can do `datetime.strptime(date_str, format)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Fetch today's date
date = datetime.today()

string_date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S')

# Variable for log file 
log_file = os.getcwd()
print(log_file)
os.mkdir("Logs12")
f = open(f"Password_Expiry_Date_Log_{string_date}.txt", "w+")

f.close()

#Date Calculations
date_before = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
days_after = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)
```

I also updated your string names to conform to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Edit: I also improved your syntax, please remember that you always need to close your files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. However I'm still getting this error after trying your solution 'AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'datetime'.

Comment: No problem mate :)